# Katana Webserver not finding clientSecret

Tags: owin, katana

I downloaded the katana project and wanted to try the client/server in the sandbox project.

I rand into a problem at for OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext :

```
public bool TryGetFormCredentials(out string clientId, out string clientSecret)
{
    clientId = Parameters.Get(Constants.Parameters.ClientId);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(clientId))
    {
        clientSecret = Parameters.Get(Constants.Parameters.ClientSecret);
        ClientId = clientId;
        return true;
    }
    clientId = null;
    clientSecret = null;
    return false;
}
```

clientSecret is null and hence the following do not validated the client.

```
    private Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        string clientId;
        string clientSecret;
        if (context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret) ||
            context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
        {
            if (clientId == "123456" && clientSecret == "abcdef")
            {
                context.Validated();
            }
            else if (context.ClientId == "7890ab" && clientSecret == "7890ab")
            {
                context.Validated();
            }
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure the client_secret param doesn't contain a space in your post

```
client_secret[space] will fail.
```

Comment: i just marked it as the answer, since this is over a year ago i created the post and I am not even sure if the katana repository looks like this anymore. Thanks for replying still.

Comment: Thanks @pksorensen. Yeah I posted this answer since I ran into this today when posting my params apparently the Owin.Security.OAuth framework doesn't trim space on the incoming parameters.